# I created a SharePoint form with Nintex now where do I find it?

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I created a form about 6 months ago for a SharePoint site I created for work. I need to edit this form, but don't remember where to get into the Nintex form editing section so I can make updates. Can anyone tell me where to go to get into my form setting?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the list of the item form.
2. Click on List tab
3. Click on Nintex Forms
4. Click on "Customize the Item Form"

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the list or library for which you made this form.
2. Go to list on the ribbon.
3. Select nintex forms or info path button based on how you created the form.